# Why does exporting a plot in raster graphics formats add a red background?

Tags: graphics, bugs, export

**Bug introduced in 12.0 or earlier and persisting in 12.3.1**

---

I've generated a *Mathematica* plot. When I right-click it and save it in a SVG file format like PDF or EPS, it looks great. (Unfortunately, I can't post an example, because Stack Exchange doesn't support SVG formats.) But when I save it in a raster file format like PNG, GIF, or JPEG, this weird red background appears that isn't in the plot displayed in Mathematica:
[image]

It looks like an error notification, but it only appears in the saved graphic and not in the *Mathematica* notebook.

But if I copy the *Mathematica* plot and then paste it into a graphics editing program like Paint, the red background is gone and I can save it in a raster format through the graphics editing program:
[image]

Any idea why this is happening, and how I can export a plot directly from *Mathematica* into a raster file format without needing this awkward cludge of copying and pasting into a graphics editor?

*Mathematica* v12.0.0.0. In case it's helpful, here's the command that I used to generate the plot from a new kernel:

```
Plot[{x^4, 320 x - 624, 256 (x - 4) + 256}, {x, 2, 6}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick}, {Black, Thickness -> Automatic}, {Black, Thickness -> Automatic}}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, LightBlue}, 1 -> {{3}, LightOrange}}, Axes -> False, Epilog -> {{PointSize[Large], Point[{4, 4^4}]}, Line[{{2, 2^4}, {4, 4^4}}], Line[{{4, 4^4}, {6, 6^4}}], Line[{{4, 4^4}, {4, 656}}]}
```

Comment: `Export["test.png", %]`

Comment: @cvgmt Thanks, that works correctly. Any idea why manually saving as doesn't? Are you getting the same red background issue if you try?

Comment: Yes, I getting the same error when I manually saving it. 12.3.1 version.

Comment: @cvgmt Think it's a bug? Should I report it?

Comment: @tparker Yes, it is a bug. Please report it to the support. Reproduced in version 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64 when saving the plot as PNG from mouse right-click on the plot.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Reported to Wolfram support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should have shown the pink box from the very beginning (which IMO is the actual bug).  `Thickness->Automatic` is not a valid Graphics directive.

[image: Ignoring invalid graphics directive "Thickness[Automatic]".]